# Please explain the phrase 'resistance'?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

When electrons move against the opposition of resistance, "friction" is generated. Just like mechanical friction, the friction produced by electrons flowing against a resistance manifests itself in the form of heat.

What is opposition mean here? 
Can someone explain this phrase and my English is not good so keep it simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

"opposing" just means "against". An opposing force is a force that pushes in the direction against something else. For example, friction is a force opposing the motion since it always works in the opposite direction as the motion and tries to stop the motion.

Resistance is in the same manner just something that tries to stop the motion. It *opposes* the motion. And the sentence says that it does that by introducing *friction* against the moving electrons.

Answer (score 0):

"Oppose" comes from the Latin "ob" (against) and "ponere" (to set or place). It literally means "place against". In battle, an "opponent" is the one who stands facing you.

When electrons try to flow in a wire, they come across all kinds of obstacles. Imagine the electrons are an army of soldiers running down the hill towards the enemy's capital city. If there are no enemy troops on the hill, they run faster and faster - lots of soldiers will arrive at the gates of the city very quickly.

Now imagine that there are enemy troops on the hill, defending the city. The soldiers keep having to stop and fight - their movement is "opposed" by the enemy soldiers, and they advance more slowly.

So it is with charge carriers. If there is little resistance, they travel long distances between interactions (times when they are scattered and lose their forward momentum), and lots of electrons arrive per unit time. As the resistance increases, the electrons spend more of their time scattering, and less moving forward.

And during the scattering, the electrons transfer their momentum and energy to the lattice (the body of the conductor). This makes the atoms move more violently, and causes heating of the conductor. This can lead to the wire glowing (filament) or even melting.